# Xcode 10 iOS 12 iPhone Simulator haven't boot in each device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

I update Xcode 10 iOS 12.0 in apple developer website the last few days.I download .zip unpackage to use.I want to use iPhone Simulator,but it's not work.All the time,it pause start up page screen.This Xcode isn't beta.Who can help me or tell me why?

[image: iPhone XS Max -12.0]

[image: iPhone 8Plus-12.0]

Comment: Why have you updated it from Apple Website and not from App Store?

Comment: I can use this url https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ to download .zip file. Dowload only effect of network.App Store can slowly.Also I think it's not point,it's ok.

Comment: Uninstall and re-install it again.

Answer (score 0):

I remove this Xcode from `Finder`.And then I unzip new `Xcode`.It's ok.I think Apple Xcode has bug,it's the same as usually developer.